# LSTM ONNX model with batch_size >1 :Non-zero status code returned while running ScatterElements

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, torch, onnx, onnxruntime

I have deep learning model with LSTM layer. While performing model inference, I am getting the below error:
`InvalidArgument: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : Non-zero status code returned while running ScatterElements node. Name:'ScatterElements_880' Status Message: Indices vs updates dimensions differs at position=0 32 vs 1` 
It works only with batch size = 1, which is slowing down inference process a lot.

How do I make it work with batch_size >1?

Packages:
Model opset : 14
pytorch version: 1.10
onnx: 1.11.0
onnxruntime: 1.9.0